# Flutter and Android Studio: Code completion prioritizes Icons package

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Please see attached. I'm trying to generate a simple print statement, but `Icons` is being displayed as my first option.  Does anybody have idea of what's causing my IDE to do this?

Thanks,

T

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can change that priority, it's built into Android Studio.